# Need to update GTK to 3.6.0 (Ubuntu 12.04 64b)

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to build Rhythmbox from it's source and I resolved all other dependancies, but this one remains:

```
Requested 'gtk+-3.0 >= 3.6.0' but version of GTK+ is 3.
```

I can't figure out how to upgrade my GTK+ version. Any help?

Comment: What version do you have installed? Do you have `-dev` package for Gtk+-3.0 installed? What is the output of `pkg-config --modversion gtk+-3.0`? In case it is < 3.6.0 (most likely the case) you may have to install Gtk and its dependencies from source (preferably to non-`/usr` prefix) & set env variables like `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the path you have built/installed newer libraries to and build Rhythmbox.